# Facebook app, show 'review the info you provide' instead of 'public profile'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I created FB Login using facebook sdk. How can I achive 'review the info you provide' instead of 'public profile' on login popup window.
My current permissions are public_profile, email, user_friends.

From:

[image]

TO :

[image]

Comment: That’s simply the old v1 login dialog vs the new v2 one. Using the new JS SDK and specifying the version, as Ila said, will get you the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this before calling FB.login(), calling without any login scope or give appropriate scope values. USE JavaScript API for login and make sure You're using the appropriate login versions!

```
 FB.init({
                        appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access                         // the session
                        xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
                        version: 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself. the problem is version of sdk. After replaced 
`https://connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js`
 to 
`https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js` it works fine.